# What happens if stdin fills up?

Tags: c, operating-system, buffer, stdin, buffer-overflow

This seems like a simple question, but I have had a really hard time finding an answer. I am writing a program in C where this seems possible (though remotely so) on some systems, as it appears there are situations where stdin has a buffer of only 4k.

So, my question is, is there a standard way an OS deals with stdin filling up (i.e., a de facto standard, a posix requirement, etc)? How predictable is the outcome, if there is in fact some sort of standard way to deal with the situation?

Comment: Just a clarification, you're not talking about the standard C I/O `stdin` here, right? Then the answer is easy: When the kernel sees that a buffer is full it could just block the process filling the buffer. Note that the process filling the "input" buffers is usually different from the process that actually consumes the input (i.e. terminal program versus application using the standard library to read input from its `stdin` `FILE` pointer).

Comment: I don't see a situation where this really matters. In general, a writing end (e.g. through a pipe) will have blocking writes block and non-blocking writes fail. Could you clarify *why* this is a concern? I think it shouldn't be.

Comment: @FelixPalmen He might just be curious. It would still be interesting to learn how the OS handles this, even if it is an extreme edge case.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I'm not sure I know any difference between the standard C I/O stdin and any other stdin. Please correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't the stdin stream used in C get associated with a buffer that the OS uses to write input to? What other sense of stdin are you referring to?

Comment: @FelixPalmen, if what you are saying is a standard way that OS's can be expected to handle the problem- If the write just gets blocked until the program reads some data, that describes the behavior completely. So, if I have a 4k buffer and I pipe another process that writes 5k, that process will just stall until some reading happens? Can I count on that happening?

Comment: There are *many* layers between an application reading from the standard C `stdin` handle, and the actual keyboard input, where each and every layer is having their own buffer. And like I said the standard C `stdin` buffer will never be filled automatically, it's only filled when you do an input operation (`scanf` or `fread` or something similar). If the buffers on the lower levels inside the kernel fills up, then the kernel simply blocks (pauses) the process filling the buffer. The only way to get a buffer overflow anywhere is if there's a bug.

Comment: @KyleStewart C provides an own layer of buffering, see for example [`setvbuf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) and Joachim assumed you talk about kernel buffers. And yes, writes getting blocked is predictable, otherwise the system would be broken.

Comment: Well, that clears things up, thanks!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The stdin buffer is filled automatically. Scanf and cin clear the buffer, not fill it.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OS will have a buffer that stores the unread stdin input. In general things writing to stdin will be using blocking calls so that if the buffer fills up they will simply stall until room is available, so no data will be lost. If this is the undesirable behaviour (you don't want to be blocking the writer) then you need to make sure you are reading the buffer in time so that it doesn't fill up.

One thing you could do is create a worker thread that simply sits in a tight loop reading the stdin as fast as it can and puts the data somewhere else (in a much larger buffer for example) and then the main program accesses the data from your new buffer rather than reading from stdin itself.